# Failed to resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2

Tags: android, firebase, admob, google-play-services

I am going through the testing tutorial [Admob tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start) while using the latest Android Studio and tools.

After the sync, I got an error:

```
Failed to resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2
Install repository and sync project
Open file
Show in project structure dialog
```

How would I get this library to resolve?

Comment: So did you click 'Install repository and sync'?

Comment: Yes, but nothing happened

Answer (score 2):

You should install the Google Play Service and Google Repository to resolve the error. Here the step in Android Studio 2.1:

> 1. Go to menu Tools -> Android ->SDK Manager.
> 2. Click SDK Tools tab
> 3. Check Google Play Service and Google Repository.
> 4. Then Ok to download them

Comment: Already installed play service and repository using SDK manager

Comment: shouldn't you use com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.2  instead com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2 ?

Comment: I changed firebase-ads to play-services-ads but same error occurred.

Comment: Have you add in your project level build gradle: classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0', and on your app gradle: apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services ?

Comment: Yes. Everything same as admob new tutorial.

Comment: there should be no problem if you following all the step on tutorial. Try cleaning and restarting your AS.

Comment: AS works fine. Only admob related project templates are not working